# Error saving workspace in ColdFusion Builder

Tags: coldfusionbuilder

Suddenly I'm getting an odd error popping up every few minutes.

> 'Periodic workspace save.' has encountered a problem.
>
> Could not write workspace metadata '{workspace}.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources.snap'.

[image: error dialog]

I've checked and the file is there. It's not marked "read-only".

Nothing's changed recently. I am on a Citrix VM running Windows 7 and my workspace is on a mapped drive. However, this setup has been running fine for over a year.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up creating a new workspace and moving my projects over there. Fortunately there weren't many (nor did I have too many snippets) and I could recustomize the way I wanted.

This is not a very good solution, however, and I'd love to see a better way to fix this issue.